# Java: java.io.File class

Tags: java, file

I started learning about java's I/O part and something seemed a bit weird to me. So, most of the classes in java.io package throw IOException, but for some reason, java.io.File doesn't. Why is it so?

If we do something like this:

```
File file = new File("theFilePath");
```

What if this file doesn't exist? Shouldn't this throw (in this case) FileNotFoundException? I know you can check for something like that through it's methods, like isFile() or exists() (I guess). 
But why doesn't java provide specific exceptions for cases like that, just like for FileReader or similar classes?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)? You are misunderstanding what that constructor does.

Comment: Exceptions should be used for exceptional cases, not basic logic.

Answer (score 0):

The File class constructor will not fail if the file does not already exists

If you want it to throw an error use

```
boolean fileExists = file.exists();
```

in a try catch block.

Actual Java Exceptions are used for exceptional cases, and aren't employed for basic logic.